# Does PayPal accept American express for subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to implement PayPal payment gateway integration.

Currently I use "PayPal checkout" API and it works for me.
Most important thing is to support AMEX.

Now I need subscriptions.

I was choosing between "Payments Pro" API  and subscriptions API.

But then I noticed here https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/payment-solutions

That PayPal pro doesn't support AMEX.

I concerned now, in a subscription section they say nothing about support of AMEX.

Do they support AMEX card in their subscription services?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to PayPal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical support gave me the answer.

> The answer to the question is yes! We do support American Express with recurring payments!